# ajaxpro 2.0 : IE 10 sends an error when an ajax function is in the callback function

Tags: .net, callback, internet-explorer-10, ajaxpro

I use Ajaxpro.2 in a .net 4.0 Application. An ordinary Ajax-Function works perfect but when i want to add another Ajax-Function in the callback function IE 10 sends a Script Error 16389 in core.ashx in line 412: this.xmlHttp.open("POST", this.url, async); 
This Error only occurs in IE10!!!

Greets and thx
Michael

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I was using an old version of AjaxPro. I updated it to the 9.2.17.1 (http://ajaxpro.codeplex.com/releases/view/23363). I added it again to the project and it worked.